# MySQL: Add multiple columns after GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, pivot

I am trying to do following:

```
SELECT 
  customer_entity.email,
  customer_entity.website_id 
FROM
  customer_entity 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      email 
    FROM
      customer_entity 
    GROUP BY email 
    HAVING COUNT(email) > 1) dupes 
    ON customer_entity.email = dupes.email  
GROUP BY customer_entity.`entity_id` 
ORDER BY customer_entity.email ;
```

Above query returns the result below:

```
email               website_id
abe@abc.com             1
abe@abc.com             2
abe@abc.com             3
abe@abc.com             4
test@abc.com            1
test@abc.com            2
test@abc.com            4
xyz@abc.tv              1
xyz@abc.tv              2
xyz@abc.tv              3
```

But I want data in below format:

```
email           website1    website2    website3    website4

abe@abc.com         1           2           3           4 
test@abc.com        1           2           null        4
xyz@abc.tv          1           2           3           null
```

is it possible in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Search for mysql pivot.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    email,
    max(website_id = 1) website_1,
    max(website_id = 2) website_2,
    max(website_id = 3) website_3,
    max(website_id = 4) website_4
from customer_entity
group by email
having count(*) > 1
order by email
```

Note that this simplifies your original query - a self-join is not needed here.

Also, this puts 0/1 values in each column that indicates whether the given email exists for this website - I find that it is more meaningful than repeating the website id in the column.